# Mailchimp template issue with repeatable content

Tags: api, templates, mailchimp

I recently made my first template for mailchimp.
The issue i am running into is that when i am setting up my mail and i delete a section in the campaign builder, it removes the last repeatable section instead of the section i wanted, and it removes the content from several other sections.

Any idea what might be the problem?
Below is an example of one such section:

```
<!-- // Begin Template img-left \\ -->
<div mc:repeatable="contentmodule" mc:variant="left-Image">
<table cellspacing="15x" cellpadding="0" width="600px">
<tr>

<td width="180px" valign="top">
<img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/placeholder_260.gif" style="max-width:180px;" mc:label="image" mc:edit="image02"></td>

<td width="375px" valign="top" text-align="justify">
<div mc:edit="img-left00"><span class="h2">Title</span><p>Tekst with the image on the left.</p></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- // End Template img-left \\ -->
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just how the MailChimp system works.  It will always add one to the end, and always remove the end one too.

You can reorder things sometimes by dragging your module to the end, and then pressing minus which will remove the correct block.

MailChimp will try to understand what you are doing and add in content that was previously there.  Due to this you should be careful if you update your template, sometimes it won't honour the change.  Try duplicating your campaign and reselecting your template if that happens.